# Regex doesn't match with some characters

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a problem with this regex : `\s*\(0\)\s*|\s*\(\)*`

I have this :

```
+33 (0)1 75 32 33 34
+ (33) (0) 1 55 24 72 67
```

And I want this :

```
+331 75 32 33 34
+331 55 24 72 67
```

the actual result of my regex is :

```
+331 75 32 33 34
+33)1 55 24 72 67
```

Can you help me to find the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
\s*\(0\)\s*|\s*[()]\s*
```

*Edit:*

The suggestion of Avinash Raj in the comments `\s*\(0\)\s*|\s*[()]\s*|^0` will remove the `0` at the begining.
 
If you want to replace this `0` with `33`, you have to use a second substitution:

Search for `^0`  and replace it with `33`

Comment: Thank's it's working well ;) I found this solution : \s*\(0\)\s*|\s*\(\)*|\) but your's is more clean

Comment: And sometimes I have this : 0130383939 can I replace the first 0 by +33 ? or if it's not possible delete the first 0 at least ?

Comment: `\s*\(0\)\s*|\s*[()]\s*|^0`

Comment: Thank's M42 I finally used the function replace of vba for that and it's working like I want. Latest question : where I have to put the \*s (I think it's that) to delete all spaces ?

Comment: @JeromeCampeaux: Sorry, I don't get you. If you want to replace all spaces, replace `\s+` by nothing. Could you edit your question and add some sample strings and expected output.